# How to navigate to fragment by clicking on toolbar icon Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have an ImageButton in my `AppBar` and now I'd love to navigate to a `settings`-fragment on click.

I already got a `Navigation Graph XML specification` for my `settings` fragment that looks like the following:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:name="try.settingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/settings_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings">
    </fragment>
```

Now what i'd love to do is to specify an `OnClickListener` that simply navigates to the specified page, so I tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AppCompatImageButton settingsButton = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_settings_button);

    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            navigate();
        }
    });

}

private void navigate() {
    Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.toolbar_settings_button).navigate(R.id.settings);
}
}
```

Resulting in:

```
    app:id/toolbar_settings_button} does not have a NavController set
```

So how do I register anything that is not a fragment in my `navigation.xml`? I have never seen anything else specified there, but the app bar is not a fragment at all.

**Edit**

The problem seems to be related to my toolbar specification - it is outside the `NavHostFragment`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appbar_include"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation">
    </fragment>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar_include"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The app bar code (the element interesting for me is the `@+id/toolbar_settings_button`):

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="342dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:maxWidth="1000000dp" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings_button"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_icon_foreground"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `findNavController().navigate(navAction)` inside your click listener?

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira I updated the code a little - sadly it  turns out to be the same error. Might that be because I forgot something about the lifecycle? Since this is the first Activity that gets initialized.

Comment: @Rüdiger I'm wondering if my answer works for you or not

Answer (score 1):

`app:id/toolbar_settings_button` does not have a NavController set but your `nav_host_fragment` does

```
private void navigate() {
    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB);
}
```

Make sure you built Navigation Graph correctly.
In navigation graph .xml may have something like:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_test_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragmentA"
        android:label="fragment_a"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.ui.fragmentB"
        android:label="fragment_b"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" >
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

fragmentB is your settingsFragment.

action id is used to navigate from current fragment to the next one